# Calling a function with giving some value

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I want to call a function with giving it a value.

Calling a function like this:

```
call myfunction(myvalue)
```

And Using the value in the function.

```
Function myfunction

'Here I want to use some value from a Private Sub()

msgbox myvalue

End Function
```

I know it is very simple, but I cannot find any solution.

Comment: check this link for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263527(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would give the function a parameter/argument.

So in pseudo code (I dont know VBA):

```
Function myfunction(myvalue)

  msgbox myvalue

End Function

call myfunction(myvalue)
```

Hope that does the trick.

Comment: I´m ashamed. That´s it. More simple than simple!